# Troubleshoot login with ldap in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ldap

My organization has made access to Jenkins CI (dockerized) stricter by enabling AD with ldap plugin. All access to our Jenkins instance require the user to be granted a single role. Even though I do have the role granted, I am unable to login. Since my organization is split into multiple organization units I suspect there is an issue with the ldap filter specified in the plugin.

We have tried troubleshooting with groovy script from https://plugins.jenkins.io/ldap/

```
Checking the name 'Role-BlaBla-Dev'...
  It is a USER: org.acegisecurity.userdetails.UserDetails$1@58faef7b
  Has groups/authorities: [Role-system-qa, authenticated]

Checking the name 'MyUserName'...
  It is a GROUP: hudson.security.LDAPSecurityRealm$GroupDetailsImpl@5e4f6228  

Checking the name 'AnotherUserNameWithAccess'...
  It is a USER: org.acegisecurity.userdetails.UserDetails$1@56d7bb22
  Has groups/authorities: [...]
```

What I see is that my username always prints with "It is a GROUP:". While a user that is able to login print "It is a USER:". What possibly distinguishes a group from a user? Any points on how to debug further is much appreciated.

Security Config from config.xml looks something like this:

```
  <useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
  <authorizationStrategy class="hudson.security.GlobalMatrixAuthorizationStrategy">
    <permission>GROUP:hudson.model.Hudson.Administer:Role-BlaBla-Dev</permission>
  </authorizationStrategy>
  <securityRealm class="hudson.security.LDAPSecurityRealm" plugin="ldap@2.12">
    <disableMailAddressResolver>false</disableMailAddressResolver>
    <configurations>
      <jenkins.security.plugins.ldap.LDAPConfiguration>
        <server>ldaps://ldapserver-org.no</server>
        <rootDN>OU=DSA,OU=Customers,DC=db1,DC=orgname,DC=no</rootDN>
        <inhibitInferRootDN>false</inhibitInferRootDN>
        <userSearchBase></userSearchBase>
        <userSearch>sAMAccountName={0}</userSearch>
        <groupSearchBase>ou=groups</groupSearchBase>
        <groupMembershipStrategy class="jenkins.security.plugins.ldap.FromUserRecordLDAPGroupMembershipStrategy">
          <attributeName>memberOf</attributeName>
        </groupMembershipStrategy>
        <managerDN>CN=Service Account SVC-Jenkins-Test-JHZ,OU=ServiceAccounts,OU=Administration,OU=JHZ,OU=Customers,DC=db1,DC=orgname,DC=no</managerDN>
        <managerPasswordSecret>{XXXXXXXXXX}</managerPasswordSecret>
        <displayNameAttributeName>displayname</displayNameAttributeName>
        <mailAddressAttributeName>mail</mailAddressAttributeName>
        <ignoreIfUnavailable>false</ignoreIfUnavailable>
      </jenkins.security.plugins.ldap.LDAPConfiguration>
    </configurations>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was related to configuration of rootDN. Removing OU=DSA resolved the problem. The groovy script now correctly identifies me with "It is a USER:"